# mac how to get the symlink original path

Tags: node.js, linux, macos, symlink

I have symlinked a file in hard drive **A** in **linux** with nodejs [`symlink`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v15.x/api/fs.html#fs_fspromises_symlink_target_path_type). When I plug the hard drive to macbook, the symlink breaks because the mounted root direcotry in macOS is different to linux. Is there a way in macOS to get the file's original path string with node, so I can use it by replacing the mounted directory in order to read the original file in the hard drive?

For example,

- in linux link: `/media/A/src/abc.jpg` -> `/media/A/dst/1.jpg`
- in mac, read `/Volumes/A/dst/1.jpg`'s link `/media/A/src/abc.jpg`, then manual change to `/Volums/A/src/abc.jpg` to read the file

Answer (score 0):

Use relative paths instead of absolute paths in the symlinks. E.g.

```
/media/A/src/abc.jpg -> ../dest/1.jpg
```

Then the links will work the same no matter where the drive is mounted.